# list of brands not displaying in a spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hi in the below code I am displaying two spinner one is for displaying brand name and another for displaying model name.

I am getting the response from server like this:
{"RESULT":"SUCCESS","BRANDS":[{"BRANDID":"14","BRANDNAME":"471"},{"BRANDID":"3","BRANDNAME":"ACE"},{"BRANDID":"4","BRANDNAME":"ADLER"},{"BRANDID":"5","BRANDNAME":"ALIEN"},{"BRANDID":"6","BRANDNAME":"ARTISAN-TORO"},{"BRANDID":"7","BRANDNAME":"ASSOCIATED PACIFIC"},{"BRANDID":"8","BRANDNAME":"ASTEX"},{"BRANDID":"9","BRANDNAME":"BERNINA"},{"BRANDID":"10","BRANDNAME":"BONIS"},{"BRANDID":"11","BRANDNAME":"BROTHER"},{"BRANDID":"12","BRANDNAME":"BROTHER "},{"BRANDID":"13","BRANDNAME":"CHANDLER"},{"BRANDID":"15","BRANDNAME":"CINCINNATI"},{"BRANDID":"16","BRANDNAME":"CONSEW"},`{"BRANDID":"17","BRANDNAME":"CONSEW\/SEIKO"},{"BRANDID":"18","BRANDNAME":"DENNISON"},{"BRANDID":"19","BRANDNAME":"DURKOPP ADLER"},{"BRANDID":"20","BRANDNAME":"EAGLE"},{"BRANDID":"21","BRANDNAME":"EASTMAN"},{"BRANDID":"22","BRANDNAME":"EASTMAN CARDINAL"},{"BRANDID":"23","BRANDNAME":"ECONOSEW"},{"BRANDID":"1","BRANDNAME":"usha"}]}`

Model Response:

{"RESULT":"SUCCESS","MODELS":[{"MODELNAME":"150","MODELID":"2"},{"MODELNAME":"C150WS","MODELID":"3"},{"MODELNAME":"HC720A","MODELID":"4"}

Based on the brand i want to display model names.

**java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}
    Fragment fragment = null;

    String userId,companyId;
    private String brandid = "3";
    public static List<LeadResult.Users> list;
    public static List<BrandResult.Brands> listBrands;
    public static List<ModelResult.Models> listModels;
    public static ArrayList<String> listBrands_String;
   // public static List<BrandResult.Brands> list1;
    String[] brand_name;
    Spinner spinner1;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ActionBar actionBar=getActivity().getActionBar();
final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_ownview, container, false);
        spinner1=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.brand1);
        mTxt_OwnView=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_OwnView);
        mTxt_PublicView =(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_PublicView);
        mRel_Ownview=(RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ownview);
        mRel_publicview =(RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.publicview);

        listBrands = new ArrayList<BrandResult.Brands>();

        listBrands_String = new ArrayList<String>();
        listModels = new ArrayList<ModelResult.Models>();

private void getBrands() {

        String brandjson = JSONBuilder.getJSONBrand();
        String brandurl = URLBuilder.getBrandUrl();

        Log.d("url","" + brandurl);
        SendToServerTaskBrand taskBrand = new SendToServerTaskBrand(getActivity());
        taskBrand.execute(brandurl, brandjson);
        Log.d("brandjson", "" + brandjson);


    }

    private void setBrand(String brandjson)
    {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper_brand = new ObjectMapper();

        try

         {
            BrandResult brandresult_object = objectMapper_brand.readValue(brandjson, BrandResult.class);

            String Brand_result = brandresult_object.getRESULT();
            Log.d("Brand_result","" + Brand_result);


            if(Brand_result.equals("SUCCESS"))
            {
                listBrands =brandresult_object.getBRANDS();
                spinner_fn();

                Log.i("listbrands", " " + listBrands);

                // startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Contact_Activity.class));

            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to load data please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return eNames;

    }

    public class SendToServerTaskBrand extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

        private Context mContext = null;
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        public SendToServerTaskBrand(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String Burl = params[0];
            String Bjson = params[1];
            String Bresult = UrlRequester.post(mContext, Burl, Bjson);

            return Bresult;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            setBrand(result);
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }


    private void getModels() {

        String model_url = URLBuilder.getModelUrl();
        String model_json = JSONBuilder.getJSONModel(brandid);

        Log.d("model_json", "" + model_json);
        SendToServerTaskModel taskModel = new SendToServerTaskModel(getActivity());
        taskModel.execute(model_url, model_json);


    }

    private void setModel(String json)
    {

        ObjectMapper objectMapperModel = new ObjectMapper();

        try
        {
           ModelResult modelresult_object = objectMapperModel.readValue(json, ModelResult.class);

            String model_result = modelresult_object.getRESULT();
            Log.d("model_result","" + model_result);


            if (model_result.equals("SUCCESS"))
            {
                listModels =modelresult_object.getMODELS();

                Log.i("listmodels", " " + listModels);


                // startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Contact_Activity.class));

            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to load data please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return eNames;

    }

    public class SendToServerTaskModel extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

        private Context mContext = null;
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        public SendToServerTaskModel(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String url = params[0];
            String json = params[1];
            String result = UrlRequester.post(mContext, url, json);

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            setModel(result);
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }


    private void spinner_fn() {


        for(int i = 0; i < listBrands.size(); i++){

            listBrands_String.add(listBrands.get(i).toString());
            Log.d("string is",""+ listBrands_String);
        }

        //ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getApplicationContext()
         //       ,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,listBrands_String);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext()
               ,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listBrands_String);

       // ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.category_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);


        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int position, long id) {

                Log.e("Position new",""+ listBrands_String.get(position));

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: what's the problem in this ??

Comment: spinner dropdown values was showing 1.Array List One but i want to display brand names like above json output

Comment: what i'm seeing is only one value for each brand in you Json response !!!

Comment: no brand name i want to display in spinner

Comment: clicking the dropdown it was showing array Item One